# Even if client id is correct its giving invalid client_id message in authorize callback

Tags: ios, react-native, oauth, strava

### Issue

I am using this library to do OAuth with [Strava](https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/). It works fine till redirecting a user to the authentication page of Strava but the issue comes once the user approves the application.
In error, it says that client_id is invalid but actually it isn't because 1) I double checked 2) If that's the case then it should give an error when opening authentication page but it didn't.

I don't know what is the best way to debug the error. I tried setting up debugger in Xcode but it didn't work as I was not getting a clear picture through debugging points.

I am pasting my code below:

**App.js**

```
import { authorize, refresh, revoke } from 'react-native-app-auth';

config = {
    issuer: 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize',
    clientId: '***',
    clientSecret: '*********',
    redirectUrl: 'myapp://myapp.com/'
    serviceConfiguration: {
      authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize',
      tokenEndpoint: 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token',
      revocationEndpoint: 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/deauthorize'
    },
    additionalParameters: {
      response_type: 'code',
      approval_prompt: 'force',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    },
    scopes: ['activity:read']
  };

try {
    const authState = await authorize(this.config);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

**Info.plist (iOS)**

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>myapp://myapp.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"myapp"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {
 return [self.authorizationFlowManagerDelegate resumeExternalUserAgentFlowWithURL:url];
}

@end
```

I don't know what is the issue. Is it something related to code or Am I passing data wrong?

Comment: Please change the `CFBundleURLSchemes` value from `myapp://myapp.com` to `myapp` and then give a try.

Comment: @AnshulBhatheja no it didn't help. I think the scheme is correct as its redirecting to the app after authentication but looks like something is going wrong when it's trying to fetch token.

Comment: Let me explain my app flow to you, then you can check which step is causing the problem: 1. Firstly I hit this url in my app browser to open the strava login page: `https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=myapp://myapp.com&scope=view_private,write&client_id=*****&response_type=code&state=ios&approval_prompt=force&`.

Comment: 2. When user login to the strava and authorize the app, then I get a certain code from the response. 3. Then I hit another api to get the token, which is: `https://www.strava.com/oauth/token` and I send three parameters with this api they are: `client_secret`, `client_id`, `code`. Client Id and Client secret you get while creating app on strava and code is which you get from the previous api response. When I hit this api I will get the token in response.

Comment: Are you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @AnshulBhatheja not didnt work. Still getting same error.

Comment: @AnshulBhatheja found out that its due to client_id & client_secret no passed while fetching token after authorization 

Url had the following parameters but client_id & client_secret was missing

`code={code}&code_verifier={code_verifier}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&grant_type=authorization_code`

Comment: Glad to know that you have solved your issue.